# @xmlrootelement json equivalent

Tags: java, json, jersey

This is the class that I use to populate and send it as a part of my web service request call:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class ClientInfo {

    private String langCode;
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private String ShipTo;
    private String timeZone;
    public String getLangCode() {
        return langCode;
    }
    public void setLangCode(String langCode) {
        this.langCode = langCode;
    }
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getShipTo() {
        return ShipTo;
    }
    public void setShipTo(String shipTo) {
        ShipTo = shipTo;
    }
    public String getTimeZone() {
        return timeZone;
    }
    public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

}
```

When I am using `Entity.xml()` for this class to parse the class and initiate the request everything works fine, and I get the result back, this is part of the code for service invocation. Please look at the last line for `Entity.xml()`;

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

ClientInfo ci = new ClientInfo();
ci.setLangCode("en");
ci.setPassword("password@123");
ci.setShipTo("0000");
ci.setTimeZone("420");
ci.setUserId("user1");
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = resourceWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.xml(ci));
```

However, if I change the `Entity.xml(ci)` to `Entity.json(ci)`, it will throw me an exception. The exception is as follow:

```
Apr 07, 2014 3:54:08 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.sheidaei.sample.appleclient.ClientInfo, genericType=class com.sheidaei.sample.appleclient.ClientInfo.
```

From what I read, my understanding is that the application can not find a JSON representation for the ClientInfo class. Is there an easy way (such as annotation) so that Entity.json() finds the JSON representation of the ClientInfo easily?

Comment: `com.telus.sample.appleclient.ClientInfo` & `com.sheidaei.sample.appleclient.ClientInfo` What is relation between them?

Answer (score 1):

By default Jersey provides support for JAXB annotated classes and XML marshalling/unmarshalling. To use JSON you need an appropriate entity provider with the proper configurations.

The Jersey documentation provides the details: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html